# mod_rewrite rule to replace %2d vs hyphen

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, urlencode

How do I setup a `RewriteCond/RewriteRule` to 301 redirect the URL

```
http://www.example.com:8080/~user/two%2dwords/more%2dwords/
```

to

```
http://www.example.com:8080/~user/two-words/more-words/
```

i.e., replacing all `%2d` encodings vs. hyphens?

Comment: try adding the `no escape` `[NE]` flag

Comment: @david: this worked for me, thank you. Mind to put your comment as an answer, so I can upvote and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the RewriteRule target URL contains special charaters those charaters can be converted to 
hexdoce by using `No escape [NE]` flag.